# Pause function while JSON call is running

Tags: ios, json, delay, steam-web-api

I would like my save button to run the JSON call and then finish it's function, but it finishes the function while running the JSON call, so the variables become initialized as `nil`.

My `DeviceDetailViewController.m`

```
//
//  DeviceDetailViewController.m
//  Steam Backpack Viewer
//
//  Created by Vishwa Iyer on 5/22/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 MoAppsCo. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DeviceDetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "ProfileManager.h"
#import "ProfileCommunicator.h"
#import "SteamProfile.h"
#import "DeviceViewController.h"

@interface DeviceDetailViewController () <ProfileManagerDelegate> {
    ProfileManager *_manager;
    NSArray *profile;
    SteamProfile *s;
}
extern NSString *ID;

@end

@implementation DeviceDetailViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BackpackViewer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.steamIDTextField.text forKey:@"steamID"];
    ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [newDevice valueForKey:@"steamID"]];


    [self startFetchingGroups]; // I would like this JSON call to finish before calling the rest of the function below


    [newDevice setValue:s.personaname forKey:@"steamName"];
    [newDevice setValue:s.avatar forKey:@"imageURL"];


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _manager = [[ProfileManager alloc] init];
    _manager.communicator = [[ProfileCommunicator alloc] init];
    _manager.communicator.delegate = _manager;
    _manager.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)startFetchingGroups
{
    [_manager fetchGroups];
}

- (void)didReceieveProfileInfo:(NSArray *)groups
{
    //the JSON call finishes here, when the groups are receives from the call. I would then like the rest of the save button method above to run after this runs, so that the s variable (which corresponds to a SteamProfile object) becomes initialized correctly.
    profile = groups;
    s = [profile objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(s.personaname);

}

- (void)fetchingGroupsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@; %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Learn how to write asynchronous code using eg completion blocks or delegation

Comment: @CarlVeazey could you show me how to do that? I have read apple's documentation on completion blocks and it's very confusing for me. I'm sorry in advance. I'm new to xcode and ios programming.

Comment: Move the second half of your `save:` function into `didReceieveProfileInfo:`?

Comment: Basically, you need to wait until you have the data before you try to do anything with it.  Don't try to pause a method in the middle, just move the completion code to run when/if the data becomes available.

Comment: @AaronBrager I tried to do that, but the problem is that how would implement the newDevice code where i use core data? I can't just take the bottom half without re-defining newDevice, and that's where i have a problem.

Comment: @VishwaIyer You could also move the stuff before `[self startFetchingGroups];` into `didReceieveProfileInfo:`.  Alternatively, you could make a property like `@property (nonatomic, strong) BackpackViewer *currentlySavingBackpackViewer;` so that you can access it from multiple methods.  (Just make sure all the methods are on the same thread.)

Comment: @AaronBrager I will trying moving everything before `[self startFetchingGroups];` into `didReceieveProfileInfo:` and tell you how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for something like this. Note this syntax could be wrong it is untested. I will leave it to you to read the documentation on function call backs.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{
    void (^_completionHandler)(int someParameter);
}

- (void)startFetchingGroups:(void(^)(int))handler;
@end



@implementation MyClass


- (void)startFetchingGroups:(void(^)(void))handler
{
    [_manager fetchGroups];
    if (handler) {
        handler();
    }
}

@end

[var startFetchingGroups:^{
     [newDevice setValue:s.personaname forKey:@"steamName"];
    [newDevice setValue:s.avatar forKey:@"imageURL"];


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

The behavior of when a callback gets called depends on what the _manager fetchGroups actually does. You could also use delegation as some of the people in the comments suggested, and is definatly a clean solution as well.

Comment: the code looks fine, but for newDevice, how do i define that variable?

Comment: Just pass it in as a parameter

Comment: Arran Brager has a comment above which tells you what to do. this is just one way to do it. You really need to just write some code and enjoy playing around with it to learn for yourself.

Comment: I understand but moving the second half of the code requires re-defining the variable `newDevice`, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Could u make new device a property of this class? Self.newDevice?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for ugly formatting. This code does exactly what you want..

```
#import "DeviceDetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "ProfileManager.h"
#import "ProfileCommunicator.h"
#import "SteamProfile.h"
#import "DeviceViewController.h"

typedef void(^EmptyBlock_t)();

@interface DeviceDetailViewController () <ProfileManagerDelegate> {
    ProfileManager *_manager;
    NSArray *profile;
    SteamProfile *s;

    //  1   
    //  here you define a block, an anonymous function pointer that will be called right after you callback is called..
    EmptyBlock_t _blockAfterJSONFetched;  
}
extern NSString *ID;

@end

@implementation DeviceDetailViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BackpackViewer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.steamIDTextField.text forKey:@"steamID"];
    ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [newDevice valueForKey:@"steamID"]];


    [self startFetchingGroups]; // I would like this JSON call to finish before calling the rest of the function below

    //  2
    //  here you assign a value to your block. Notice that all objects inside block are called "retain" automatically. Also they a called "release" when you release the block itself..
    _blockAfterJSONFetched=^{
        [newDevice setValue:s.personaname forKey:@"steamName"];
        [newDevice setValue:s.avatar forKey:@"imageURL"];


        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    };
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _manager = [[ProfileManager alloc] init];
    _manager.communicator = [[ProfileCommunicator alloc] init];
    _manager.communicator.delegate = _manager;
    _manager.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)startFetchingGroups
{
    [_manager fetchGroups];
}

- (void)didReceieveProfileInfo:(NSArray *)groups
{
    //the JSON call finishes here, when the groups are receives from the call. I would then like the rest of the save button method above to run after this runs, so that the s variable (which corresponds to a SteamProfile object) becomes initialized correctly.
    profile = groups;
    s = [profile objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(s.personaname);

    //  3
    //  finally after your callback is fired you check if block pointer is not null and if it is you call it as a casual function. Assigning nil in the end is optional..
    if(_blockAfterJSONFetched){
        _blockAfterJSONFetched();
        _blockAfterJSONFetched=nil;
    }

}

- (void)fetchingGroupsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@; %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: This code has a strong reference cycle in it and will cause a memory leak.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right. We have to capture weak reference to self. id __weak selfWeak=self; _blockAfterJSONFetched =^{  .. [selfWeak dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];};